# How do I use the answer of an .length object count in an if statement?

Tags: jquery, variable-length

I want to have some dynamics in my creation and therefor need jQuery to count the times a `div` appears within a different `div` and based upon the answer executes a function; change css to be exact.

```
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

I want jQuery to tell me the amount of `.tile` within `.tiles`

```
$(function() {
    var countOfTiles = $('.tiles > .tile').length;

    if ($('.tiles > .tile').length = 2) {
        alert('no');
    } else if ($('.tiles > .tile').length = 3) {
        alert('yes');
}
```

However, it either shows 'unexpected identifier' or else the first statement is always true..

So how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `==` for comparisons. Your current code is trying to set the length property which is readonly, hence the error

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
 $(function() {
     var countOfTiles = $('.tiles > .tile').length;

    if ($('.tiles > .tile').length == 2) {
        alert('no');
    } else if ($('.tiles > .tile').length == 3) {
      alert('yes');
}
```

the single = is for assign value and the == is for comparison